# Show or hide WooCommerce admin product custom field depending on the product type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, admin

I added an custom field to the products

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'prodcode_fields');

function prodcode_fields() {
    global $post, $thepostid, $product_object;

    echo '<div class="options_prodcode_fields">';
   
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_prodcode_good_number',
            'value' => $product_object->get_meta('_prodcode_number', true),
        'type' => 'number',
            'label' => 'Product Code',
            'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __('Product Code', 'sv-prodcode'),
        )  );

echo '</div>';
}
```

All is well, but it is necessary not to display it in variable goods. Can you tell me how to do it using woocommerce tools?

I tried to add `'class' => 'show_if_simple',` but I get nonsense - only input is hidden, but labels and so on remain.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide an additional product custom field, you can use 2 approaches:

Using the [`wrapper_class` attribute](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/wc-meta-box-functions.php#L29) with "show_if_simple" or "hide_if_variable" like:

- `'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple'`,
- `'wrapper_class' => 'hide_if_variable'`,

Or you can directly use "show_if_simple" or "hide_if_variable" in the starting `<div>` like:

```php
echo '<div class="options_prodcode_fields show_if_simple">';
```

or

```php
echo '<div class="options_prodcode_fields hide_if_variable">';
```

So in for your code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'display_admin_product_custom_setting_fields');
function display_admin_product_custom_setting_fields() {
    global $product_object;

    // Only for simple product type
    echo '<div class="options_prodcode_fields show_if_simple">';
   
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'            => '_prodcode_good_number',
            'type'          => 'number',
            'label'         => __('Product Code', 'sv-prodcode'),
            'description'   => __('Product code description', 'sv-prodcode'),
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'value'         => $product_object->get_meta('_prodcode_number'),
        )  );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

---

##### Addition

###### The different product type classes to show or hide a custom product field

###### By Default in WooCommerce:

- Product type **"simple"**: `show_if_simple` or `hide_if_simple`
- Product type **"variable"**: `show_if_variable` or `hide_if_variable`
- Product type **"external"**: `show_if_external` or `hide_if_external`
- Product type **"grouped"**: `show_if_grouped` or `hide_if_grouped`
- **Virtual** product: `show_if_virtual` or `hide_if_virtual`
- **Downloadable** product: `show_if_downloadable` or `hide_if_downloadable`

###### Some other foreign products:

- Product type **"subscription"**: `show_if_subscription` or `hide_if_subscription`
- Product type **"booking"**: `show_if_booking` or `hide_if_booking`
- Product type **"bundle"**: `show_if_bundle` or `hide_if_bundle`